# Entity Framework 7 RC1 Reverse Engineer Entire DB only?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have successfully reverse engineered my DB in EF7 RC1, specifically using the Package Manager Console command 'Scaffold-DbContext', as described in their documentation.

First, are there any options for reverse engineering just some of the tables in the DB? Most of my projects use only a few of the hundreds of tables in the DB.

Secondly, if we change the DB and want to reverse engineer it a second time what is the correct procedure? If I simply re-run the command it says 'Build failed' presumably because the models already exist.

Answer (score 1):

> are there any options for reverse engineering just some of the tables in the DB?

Yes. To see options, execute `get-help Scaffold-DbContext` in the Package Manager Console. This is the output for **7.0.0-rc1-final**. To limit selection to only some tables, use the `-Tables` options

```
PM> get-help Scaffold-DbContext

NAME
    Scaffold-DbContext

SYNOPSIS
    Scaffolds a DbContext and entity type classes for a specified database.


SYNTAX
    Scaffold-DbContext [-Connection] <String> [-Provider] <String> [-OutputDirectory <String>] [-ContextClassName <String>] [-Schemas <String[]>] [-Tables <String[]>] [-DataAnnotations] 
    [-Project <String>] [-StartupProject <String>] [-Environment <String>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Scaffolds a DbContext and entity type classes for a specified database.


RELATED LINKS
    about_EntityFramework 

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Scaffold-DbContext -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Scaffold-DbContext -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Scaffold-DbContext -full".
    For online help, type: "get-help Scaffold-DbContext -online"
```

> if we change the DB and want to reverse engineer it a second time what is the correct procedure?

Delete your old model classes and context and re-run reverse engineering from the updated database. Scaffold-DbContext does not make in-place updates in RC1.

Comment: Thanks. That -tables option works. Although "get-help Scaffold-DbContext" does not return help and "Update-Help" does not add this additional help either. I am using 7.0.0-rc1-final with the latest PM but no matter - the -tables option works even without Help knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a a known issue with the EF7 version which will be released. [Rowan Miller told this here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/ASPNET-Events/ASPNET-Fall-Sessions/Entity-Framework-7#time=3m09s).

[image]

You have to wait for the next large EF7 Update which will bring back some features that are missing.

Comment: Thanks. I can wait as I do not intend to go live with a release candidate.